# Using regex to get the value from a tag in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Using regex in PHP how can I get the 108 from this tag?

```
<td class="registration">108</td>
```

Comment: What do you actually mean by get it from the tag?

Comment: I think this is stored in a string, else it has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @Rafael I want using regex, to get the number 108 in the example, or any data (letters or not) between the td class registration

Comment: @Kaoukkos Don't use regex to parse html. Amal has a good solution for your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex isn't a good solution for parsing HTML. Use a DOM Parser instead:

```
$str = '<td class="registration">108</td>';    
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);      

$tds = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
foreach($tds as $td) { 
    echo $td->nodeValue; 
}
```

Output:

```
108
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/sWKPSSpu)

The above code loads up your HTML string using [`loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method, finds all the the `<td>` tags, loops through the tags, and then echoes the node value.

---

If you want to get only the **specific class name**, you can use an [`XPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);      

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

// get the td tag with 'registration' class
$tds = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'registration')]");

foreach($tds as $td) { 
    echo $td->nodeValue;
}
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/r6nkgVMx)

This is similar to the above code, except that  it uses XPath to find the required tag. You can find more information about XPaths in the PHP manual documentation. [This](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-dom-using-xpath/) post should get you started.

Comment: Thank you but I may need to use a lot of different td classes. So how can I do this more specific to the specific td class?

Comment: @Kaoukkos: that makes it even more appropriate to use the DOM parser rather than regex. The DOM parser is a much better tool for selecting specific elements; that's what it's built for. Regex will burn you if you try parsing complex HTML.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it in a while!

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to force regex, use the `<td class=["']?registration["']?>(.*)</td>` expression

Comment: Thank you for this but I need to have it specific for the exact `<td class="registration">`. Not for every td available in the code

Comment: Because he used `^` and `$`.

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all(): No ending delimiter '^'

Comment: Exactly... remove those.

Comment: @Kaoukkos You have to use delimiters to wrap regexp in `preg_*`.

Comment: Still will not work when someone will change html to `<td class="registration" >108</td>`. That's why we're not using regexp for such tasks.

Comment: @RápliAndrás i tried all of your suggestions, but nothing seems to work. i am upvoting anw. you dont deserve to have -2. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']'